# Can I ferment blanched cabbage?

Tags: food-safety, fermentation, cabbage, sauerkraut

I've blanched some cabbage and I wonder if I can ferment it in order to have sauerkraut.
Will it work? Will it be safe?

**Edit** I followed the recommendations and added some raw vegetables and a little bit more salt than usual. The fermentation process was fine and the end product was delicious. Note for future me, don't blanch cabbage for sauerkraut :) . It's less troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work and be safe. The one thing I'd worry about is that blanching may have reduced the amount of lactic acid bacteria available for fermentation; that might delay fermentation, or even encourage the growth of unwanted microorganisms. If possible, I'd suggest mixing the blanched cabbage with a small amount of raw cabbage (or any raw vegetable, really) before salting and packing the sauerkraut, and keeping the salt content near the higher end of the range for sauerkraut.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, two considerations; Depending on how much you cooked it and how you drain it it may mess-up the salt balance. And, I started my kruat with a little bakers yeast and sugar so did not rely on natural yeast , because you have killed the natural yeast you may need something to start it. I understand that the yeast produce lactic acid in homemade while commercial kraut has added acetic acid.

Comment: Can you clarify "salt balance?"  I would assume the blanch took place before any salt was added.  Also, what is the second consideration?  This process is not really about yeast, though I realize it is naturally there (pre-blanch)...it is more about the bacteria that are supported to produce lactic acid.

Comment: When I made it , recipe called for some amount of salt per cup of shredded raw cabbage. The salt pulled out water and so after after several minutes the brine level was basically at the top of the cabbage although no water was added. As I remember yeast and bacteria are both active.

Comment: Right, but the question is about blanched cabbage...before salting.

Comment: Sauerkraut is not yeast-fermented. Adding bakers yeast will not start anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is the way I make a quick, strong, and very flavorful sauerkraut! I slice a head of green cabbage with my Suncraft BS-271 Cabbage Slicer, add lots of Old Bay seasoning and cook in a large skillet at low heat for 15 min. Let cool, add in about 20% store bought Raw Organic Sauerkraut (for starter) and some honey into a wide-mouth mason jar with fermenting lid. This cooked cabbage ferments quickly and has a strong flavor, I give it two weeks.